# Storage folder in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, storage

We are deploying a new Laravel 5 installation and our client has said that they are unable to provide a writable directory on the web space that we are running on.

Is there any way that the storage folder can be by-passed when deploying the Laravel installation as I can only see logs and session based data that I am storing in MySQL anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Laravel official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-root-directory)

> The storage directory contains compiled Blade templates, file based sessions, file caches, and other files generated by the framework. This folder is segregated into app, framework, and logs directories. The app directory may be used to store any files utilized by your application. The framework directory is used to store framework generated files and caches. Finally, the logs directory contains your application's log files.

You could prevent laravel from using the `storage` folder only if you modify the core files of the framework, because this is how laravel is set up to work.

I strongly advise you against that. Just migrate to another enviroment and get write permissions for that folder.

I know that this is not a proper solution, but it seems more harmful to your application structure  and integrity to do core level modification.

Comment: I agree completely. Don't want to be messing around with the vendor files. Just thought there might be a way of bypassing the storage writing but I will have to force the client to allow write access to that folder. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it seems that's the only way. As I said there might be a way to do it,there always is, but it doesn't worth the effort. It's much easier to give write permissions to the folder or ask the administrator of the system to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you can move the storage to somewhere else... To the temp folder?

If that's a good opportunity for you, you can use:

```
$app->useStoragePath("/tmp/laravel_storage/");
```

Don't forget to build up the folder structure there (i.e. creating sessions, files, ...)